# Delayed bootstrapping angular 8 module from browser

Tags: angular, angular8

I've an angular library project (`LibModule`) that contains set of re-usable components. I've used Angular elements to convert them into web components so we can use in non-angular apps. I've used a dummy angular application to bundle all the scripts, styles and assets. Now the `LibModule` has a `forRoot` method that takes a configuration object. When the library is used in Angular application we can call `LibModule.forRoot` in the `AppModule`.

When it's used in non-angular apps how can I pass the configuration object at runtime from browser? How can I bootstrap the module at runtime from browser?